# Multidimensional arrays with angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am currently trying to display array data in a table using angular. Here is my HTML:

```
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Transaction Type</th>
                    <th>Direct Object</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="user in index.users">
                    <td ng-repeat="transaction in users.transactions">
                     {{transaction.transLocale}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.transDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.transTime}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.transAmount}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.transType}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.directObject}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here is my js:

```
app.controller('IndexController', function(){
    this.users = userHistory;
}); 



var userHistory = [
{
    name: 'Bobby',
    transactions: 
     [{
        transDate: '1/15/15',
        transTime: '4:30pm',
        directObject: 'Matt',
        transAmount: '11',
        transType: 'debt',
        transLocale: 'B-dubs'
    },{
        transDate: '1/12/15',
        transTime: '7:30pm',
        directObject: 'Matt',
        transAmount: '9',
        transType: 'credit',
        transLocale: 'MickDs'       
        }]
 },

{   name: 'Jake',
    transactions: [
     {
        transDate: '1/11/15',
        transTime: '1:30pm',
        directObject: 'Matt',
        transAmount: '5',
        transType: 'credit',
        transLocale: "Jason's"
    }, {
        transDate: '1/12/15',
        transTime: '7:30pm',
        directObject: 'Matt',
        transAmount: '9',
        transType: 'debt',
        transLocale: 'MickDs'       
    }]
},
    {
    name: 'Clayton',
    transactions: {
        transDate: '1/14/15',
        transTime: '2:30pm',
        directObject: 'Matt',
        transAmount: '15',
        transType: 'credit',
        transLocale: "Chen's"
    }
}];
```

I can't seem to print the data inside of the transactions array? 
I am just starting out in angular so I am not quite sure what is going on. Any insight would be wonderful, I am trying to learn more than trying to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: You are printing out {{user.transDate}} whereas it's an attribute of ```transaction``` {{transaction.transDate}}. Change others similarly

Comment: When I printed out transaction.transLocale it inserted the user names, not the location data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the first `ng-repeat` to the tbody:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="user in users">
    <tr ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        <td>{{transaction.transLocale}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.transDate}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.transTime}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.transAmount}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.transType}}</td>
        <td>{{transaction.directObject}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

It is okay to have multiple tbody elements in your table.

Comment: " change users.transactions in user.transactions in your view." what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
          <td>{{transaction.transLocale}}</td>
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
          <td>{{transaction.transDate}}</td>
          <td>{{transaction.transTime}}</td>
          <td>{{transaction.transAmount}}</td>
          <td>{{transaction.transType}}</td>
          <td>{{transaction.directObject}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Script:

```
app.controller('IndexController', function(){
    $scope.users = userHistory;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you find the plunker I made:- http://plnkr.co/edit/1GhzyeszaeGPAC2cu4ib?p=preview

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in index.users">
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.transLocale}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.transDate}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.transLocale}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.transTime}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.transAmount}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.transType}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-repeat="transaction in user.transactions">
        {{transaction.directObject}}
        <br>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```